# npm install hangs on self-hosted git runner

Tags: github-actions, npm-install

I have a self-hosted, a VM with Windows Server 2019, but when I try to do `npm install` in git actions it hangs and never ends. I guess that the npm install is not giving the proper exit code but I am not sure how to make this working. Here is my workflow:

```
jobs:
  checkout_and_build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: dev
    environment: dev

    steps:
      - name: Code checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Build
        run: |
          echo "Building - npm ci"
          set NODE_ENV=CI && npm ci --legacy-peer-deps --ignore-scripts --include=dev
          echo "Building - npm run build"
          npm run build
        shell: cmd
      - name: Deploy
        run: |
          echo "Deleting old files"
          cd %DEPLOYMENT_DIR%
          del /q assets
          echo "Copying new files"
          xcopy ${{github.workspace}}\dist\* . /Y /Q /S
          echo "Deployed!"
        shell: cmd
```

Any ideas what might be wrong? :)

When I check the folder where the source has been checkout, there is the node_modules folder and it is full. I have tried to run same command locally on the VM and it works as a charm. I have tried to delete the node_modules folder to check if it is created by the action and it is created.

Comment: Which step is causing it to hang? Did you check the CPU/RAM utilization on your self-hosted runner when it's running? Does it hang indefinitely for longer periods of time? Did you try leaving it for long time to see if it finishes?

Comment: `npm ci --legacy-peer-deps...` hangs . It executes, restores most of the node_modules but it seems that not all of them. I have tried to put the `--verbose` flag but nothing useful came up